# Can a coinbase adhering to BIP-0034 (block v2) only pay P2PKH addresses?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, output, address-format

I've been working on a bitcoin miner that uses BIP-0034 (block v2).

I'm confused about the coinbase transaction of block v2. Does block v2 only accept P2PKH type of address to allow me to receive a reward for solving a block? Because the [first block v2](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/blocks/btc/227836) uses P2PKH address on the coinbase tx.

So my question is can I use other types of address for coinbase transaction inside block v2 or I can only use the P2PKH address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no restriction. Any transaction (including coinbase transactions) can create any output type. The block reward can be spent to P2PK, P2PKH, P2SH, P2SH-P2WPKH, P2SH-P2WSH, P2WPKH, P2WSH, P2TR, or even a bare script regardless of the version of the block.

Comment: wdym sir? sorry, i dont understand

Comment: The answer to your question is "no": there is no restriction on the type of outputs/ardresses a coinbase transaction can pay to, in BIP34 or elsewhere.

Comment: so thats mean i can only use P2PKH only right?

Comment: No, you can use any type of address.